# MAC: Import .p12 certificate into the keychain via command line

Tags: bash, command-line, macos, certificates, keychain

I'm trying to import .p12 certificate into the keychain on my mac via bash script. So far, I've been trying:

1. `sudo security import` command. It returns that import was successful but, in fact, it never gets imported into any keychain.
2. `sudo  security add-certificates -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain certificate.p12`

it throws the following error:

```
Password: SecCertificateCreateFromData: Unknown format in import.
```

The only thing that worked for me was the .cer format via this command: `sudo  security add-certificates -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain certificate.cer`. It does import the certificate into the keychain and I can see it in the keychain access.

But I only have .p12 certificates. Could anyone help me with that one, please?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert it to `.pem` format first. You can do so with `openssl`and then try and import it.

To convert the certificate, you can use this command

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.p12 -out certificate.pem -passin pass:[password]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But how do I pass the import password via command itself? So that I didn't have to enter it in the terminal

I can't find it in my keychain access for some reason by the way

Comment: @ArtemNovikov Please check edit

Comment: yeah, thanks, figured it out. But I can't see the imported certificate in my keychain access. When I try to import it again, it says `certificate.pem: already in ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain`

Comment: @ArtemNovikov It would seem you already have a cert in the directory. Move it elsewhere then try the steps again to add the cert.

Comment: I manually deleted it from the keychain access before trying these steps with converting to .pem and importing again. Maybe there's something wrong with command I use to import? I'm trying it this way: `sudo  security add-certificates -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain certificate.pem`